# Why doesn't NRVO work with move constructor in visual studio 2019, msvc 1929?

Tags: c++, c++11

There is a class as follow:

```c
class HeavyObject
{
public:
    HeavyObject() { cout << "Constructor\n"; }
    ~HeavyObject() { cout << "Destructor\n"; }
    HeavyObject(HeavyObject const&) { cout << "Copy Constructor\n"; }
    HeavyObject& operator=(HeavyObject const&) { cout << "Assignment Operator\n"; return *this; }
    HeavyObject(HeavyObject&&) { cout << "Move Constructor\n"; }
private:
    // many members omitted...
};
```

Then i test NRVO:

```c
HeavyObject func()
{
    HeavyObject o;
    return o;
}

int main()
{
    HeavyObject o = func();
    return 0;
}
```

I think the output is :

```
Constructor
Destructor
```

But the real output is:

```
Constructor
Move Constructor
Destructor
Destructor
```

Why?

Comment: nrvo is not mandatory, gcc does produce the output you expect: https://godbolt.org/z/nx9xa89sP.

Comment: I get your expected output with MSVC 19.29.30037 (Visual Studio 2019, Windows 10, 64-bit build) with optimizations enabled - as also on the linked Compiler Explorer page.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number,thanks,but only RVO is of little use..

Comment: did you turn on optimizations? compilers usually don't worry too much about optimizing when you tell them to not optimize

Comment: @AdrianMole,my environment is same to you/

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number,  I find visual studio 2019 optimization is invalid（/Od） in debug, it's validin release.

Comment: of course in debug mode there may be no optimization. Only in release mode you get efficient code